# How to write dice-loss backpropogation with numpy

Tags: python, numpy, backpropagation, dice, loss-function

I am trying to write a dice-loss function by myself. Here is the forward pass I wrote. But I did not understand how to calculate the backprop. I tried to write some but it's not working. Or dice-loss does not needs back prop at all?

```
alpha = 0.5
belta = 0.5

tp = np.sum(pred * label)

fn = np.sum((1- pred ) * label)

fp = np.sum(pred * (1 - label))

dice = tp / (tp + alpha * fn + belta * fp)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that I would call that a forward pass. How do you get the `pred` ? 
Typically you need to write down the step leading to pred. Then you get your loss as you did. This defines a computational graph. And from there can start the backward pass (or backpropagation). You need to calculate the gradient starting from the end of the computational graph, and proceed backward to get the gradient of the loss with respect to the weights.
[image]
I wrote an introduction to backpropagation in a blog post (https://www.qwertee.io/blog/an-introduction-to-backpropagation) , and I suppose you should find more details about how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use calculus and the chain rule to solve this.

The Dice is defined as [image]. X is your pred and Y is your label.

For a matrix X and Y of size MxN, we can write this as [image].

Apply the quotient rule for an arbitrary value i,j in X: [image]

We can now divide by |X|+|Y| and that gives us a prety neat solution: [image]

In python:

```py
dX = (2*Y-dice)/(np.sum(X)+np.sum(Y))
```

And if you add a smooth term in the numerator and denominator of your dice:

```py
dX = (2*Y-dice)/(np.sum(X)+np.sum(Y)+eps)
```

Also if you save the Dice, |X| and |Y| variables in your forward calculation, you don't have to calculate them again in the backwards pass.